# SQL contar días de un select

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo el siguiente query y necesito sumar los días, días unicamente , de una serie de registros de entrada, hasta ahora solo tengo los días por mes, pero estos registros registros se repiten, porque tienen diferentes datos de **tiempo** y a mi interesa saber solamente por día.

```
select count(FechaVerificacion) conteo from sysCPEmpleadosBiometricoDetalle
where idSysCPEmpleados = 5 and fecha like '%08%'


select distinct * from sysCPEmpleadosBiometricoDetalle
where idSysCPEmpleados = 5 and fecha like '%08%'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿qué salida esperas obtener?

Comment: cuantos días hay sin repetir los 4 del 01 los 4 del 02 , etc ... es decir , suponiendo que hay 4 registros siempre por día serían 22.25 de conteo o solo 22

Comment: No termino de entender como debería quedar.  Si lo hicieras a mano, ¿como se vería el resultado en forma de tabla? si agregas eso a tu pregunta quedaría mucho más claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  count(distinct convert(varchar,FechaVerificacion,111)) conteo 
    from sysCPEmpleadosBiometricoDetalle
    where idSysCPEmpleados = 5 and fecha like '%08%'
```

Con `convert(varchar,FechaVerificacion,111)` convertimos la fecha a un varchar quitándole la parte de tiempo, y con `count(distinct ....)` contamos las  fechas distintas en el conjunto de filas seleccionadas

Answer (score 2):

Puedes lograr lo que buscas primero seleccionando registros con distinta fecha, y finalmente contando sobre esta sub-consulta.

La solución, utilizando un [*CTE*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), sería algo como:

```
with
qBiometricoDistintaFecha as (
select distinct idSysCPEmpleados, Fecha
  from sysCPEmpleadosBiometricoDetalle
)
select count(1)
  from qBiometricoDistintaFecha
 where idSysCPEmpleados = 5
   and fecha like '%08%'
```

Creo que el código se auto-explica.

---

Edición

**OJO**: Desconozco el tipo de dato del campo `Fecha`, pero la manera de filtrar con un like sobre la fecha me parece incorrecta. En una base de datos que tenga registros de varios años, esto traerá más de lo que esperas (agosto de distintos años, además de todos los meses del años como el `2008`, todos los años de la década del `2080` y además de el día `08` de todos los meses de todos los años. No cambié la forma de filtrar, ya que no era parte de tu duda.